# is there any option in illustrator to convert in curves by type automatically when export in vector format?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, text, export, file-format

when i have designed in illustrator finally i need to send it a printing press in a vector format. i manually convert design's type in outline by (Shift+ctrl+o). Is there any option to convert design's type in outline automatically when export in a vector format?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. If you export the document as a PDF, then there's no need to convert text to outlines.

Comment: I think the shortcut is the fastest way to do it. Select all (Ctrl+A) before converting the texts. As the shortcut works only in texts, you don't have to worry about the other objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output a PDF and automatically have the text turned to outlines, you can make yourself a new PDF Preset.

Go to

Edit >

Adobe PDF Presets...>

then make a new preset, choose an initial format such as X-1a:2001

then under Advanced tab, pick "Custom..." for transparency, and you can select to "convert all text to outlines"

Set any other settings you'd usually want, and save it.

This is an answer originally found [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/auto-outline-illustrator-text-on-pdf-save/td-p/8402578?page=1), and it has worked for me.

[image: custom transparency flattener options dialog box]

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator has no option to automatically convert type to outline on export. You can only do that manually, but you probably don't need to. Just save to PDF format and don't think about it, send it to print.