What's the best practice for outlining text for print?
Just picking your brains for how you have found to be the best practice for outlining text that you might need to update in the future.
Say I have a file that I need to outline text to send to print. But I know I will likely need to make updates to the copy in the future.
I've been saving 2 files - one with the text outlined for print and one without for edits.
Is that how most people do it? Or is there a better way?
ETA: I'm using Adobe Illustrator, and I've just always converted text to outlines, as many printers over the years have included those instructions to do so when sending over PDF files for print.
Me, making the assumption that it must be a standard requirement for printers, just made sure to always do it. Maybe I'm wrong and I can stop this madness! lol

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can't you just send the printer a PDF file?  Why are you converting the text to outlines?  What software are you using?  Please edit your question and provide more details. Thanks.

I haven't outlined type is a decade or more.. I send PDFx files. (I realize packaging often wants live files with outlined type)

In my opinion, you only need to keep 1 working file, well organized in layers.
When exporting to PDF mark the necessary checkboxes so your file is automatically converted to curves, but again, only on the export step.

The only time when I actually save an outlined and a text version is for logos or something similar, for example, different department headings, and in this the text and font name are stored in a branding manual, not in a normal everyday file.
Yes, there could be a case where you need to convert to curves. Probably you do not have a font that can be incorporated into a PDF. Keeping the text on a different layer is good enough.
On an Illustrator file, there is not much problem. If the case is on long texts, for example, an Indesign book project, it is better to choose another font.

Thank you for the info. For this - "When exporting to PDF mark the necessary checkboxes so your file is automatically converted to curves, but again, only on the export step." - how do you do this? When I'm exporting to a PDF, I do not see anywhere in the dialog box to automatically convert text to curves.
I'm going to start only converting text to curves when specifically asked to do so by the printer. I think I've been doing it unnecessarily for years now and I could save a lot of time/disk space by ending that practice.

I added a screen capture. (Stolen from here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/133859/is-there-any-option-in-illustrator-to-convert-in-curves-by-type-automatically-wh)

Most of the time you should be fine with sending just the PDF to the printer. If they need the file for some reason, you can always package the file which would include the font file.
When I have needed to outline fonts, I generally keep the type on it's own layer and then duplicate that layer. I have an editable layer of text and the outlined version available. I rarely outline fonts.
Someone may need to outline fonts because the printer may need to work with the native file to make adjustments to the artwork for printing and you are not allowed to share/package the font. I am thinking complex branding installation.

The priner should be able to flatten the font in their pdf processor application. Thats what i eo if i dont have the font but need to do something with the file.
